# SAPUI5 For the UI and LARAVEL for backoffice

Tags: php, laravel-5, hosting, sapui5, node-webkit

I have to begin a new project and that's 2 years ago that I'm working on SAPUI5, But for severals reasons I have to use the Laravel 5.1 Framework to handle the database logic and controller to get and put data from and to the database.

I appreciate the power of SAPUI5 and I would like to use it for the front-end of my app.

**My question is** : It is possible to handle a server application with those two technologies?

**My second question is** : Which hosting I have to choose, because that my client want a kind of desktop app, and for this I thought to use node webkit package. And  for that i have to launch a node server. In my goDaddy shared hosting i don't have this possibility.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: We would really appreciate some code or something not this broad that we can help you with. Specific problems show us that you've done research and have tried something.

Comment: The intention of the first question is not clear: Why should UI5 not work with Laravel? Unless you're using OData you are free to implement your backend with any server side framework you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely combine Laravel as back-end technology with SAPUI5/OpenUI5 as front-end technology. As Laravel provides the front-end with restful services, you're probably best-off leveraging the `JSONModel` in your UI5 application.

Laravel is a PHP framework, so you'll need to look for a PHP host. If a host is capable of running PHP, it is also able to serve the static UI5 content.

If you want to package your app as a desktop application, NW.js will work, but Electron will do the job too. A very nice comparison between the two frameworks can be found here: http://tangiblejs.com/posts/nw-js-electron-compared.

Please do note that both frameworks turn your application into a desktop application and will run on the desktop. You won't need to find a server that runs node.js. You do need a server that runs PHP for your back-end Laravel logic.